# Excel VBA - Export to CSV

Tags: excel, vba

Was after some input that I have so far had trouble figuring out on my own...

1. If I wanted the location (i.e. C:\Users\SB\Documents\CSV Uploads) to be stored in another sheet (LOOKUP DATA), in cell "C13" (Defined Name: FOLDERLOCATION) and used instead of having it in the code, can this be done?
2. While the below works to export the sheet to a CSV file to the folder I have specified, the file ends up being a lot larger than I expected. The file ends up being over 9mb! The weird thing is if I open, then save the file again and close, it drops down to around 38kb. Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance, I look forward to seeing what you experts think!

```
Sub EXPORTCSV()

Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String

    Sheets("UPLOAD").Visible = True
    Sheets("UPLOAD").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\SB\Documents\CSV Uploads\UPLOAD - IB " & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD - hh_mm_ss AMPM") & ".csv") _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
 
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: open the CSV file using a text editor, such as Notepad++ ... see what it taking up so much space

Comment: Thanks @jsotola! Not sure why but it was full of commas from the empty cells, looking into why.

Comment: the commas are not from empty cells ... the commas are the separators between cell data, which happen to be empty

Comment: you can use `Sheets("UPLOAD").SaveAs ...` ... no need to make sheet visible, or copy it .... in fact, the `copy` may be responsible for saving the whole sheet

Comment: The commas disappear if I open the workbook and save again, which then shrinks the file size. I also tried `Sheets("UPLOAD").SaveAs` but it saves over the top of the existing sheet, not exporting to a new workbook and then saves.

Comment: The tip to check in Notepad++ got me thinking and I found an error, thanks for the tip, I was able to fix it and the size is down to the expected size now. Thanks @jsotola!! All I need now is to figure out point 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to your point 1, yes, you can use a cell to store the root path.  I have rewritten some of your code for clarity, but if you want to keep the same structure that you already have, just replace the `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\SB\Documents\CSV Uploads\UPLOAD - IB " & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD - hh_mm_ss AMPM") & ".csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False`

with

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD").Range("C13").Value & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD - hh_mm_ss AMPM") & ".csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False`

A few other notes:

- Using `ThisWorkbook` rather than `ActiveWorkbook` is safer because it will always refer to the workbook that the VBA code is residing in rather than whichever workbook happens to be active at the time.
- Be careful with the `Workbook.Close` method, especially since there is no confirmation to close.  You could easily lose your work, and since CSV files don't save VBA code, it would be even worse.

```
Private Sub EXPORTCSV_MOD()

    ' Parameters of the file path
    Dim Path As String, Filename As String, Extension As String
    
    Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UPLOAD").Range("C13").Value
    Filename = Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD - hh_mm_ss AMPM")
    Extension = ".csv"
    
    ' Assemble the full file path
    Dim FullPath As String
    FullPath = Path & Application.PathSeparator & Filename & Extension

    ' Save and close the workbook
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FullPath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
 
    ThisWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx @TehDrunkSailor, with a slight tweak using your logic, this resolved my code, you legend!! The reason I am using Active and not This is because I am saving the copied sheet into a new workbook, not the workbook I have been working in.

```
Sub EXPORTCSV()

Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String
'The UPLOAD sheet was very hidden
    Sheets("UPLOAD").Visible = True
'Copy to a new workbook
    Sheets("UPLOAD").Copy
'Save the new workbook using data stored in the original workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LOOKUP DATA").Range("C13").Value & "UPLOAD - IB  " _
        & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD - hh_mm_ss AMPM") & ".csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

'Close the new workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```